# Почему не работает inline кнопка aiogram при активном состоянии?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, inline

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):

    await message.answer("Напиши что нибудь")
    await State.form.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=State.form)
async def start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    await message.answer("Привет! Нажмите на кнопку:", reply_markup=keyboard)

# Обработчик нажатия на inline кнопку
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == '1')
async def process_button_click(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    # Отправляем пользователю сообщение "1" без отображения на экране
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.message.chat.id, "1")
```

Кнопка не реагирует.
Когда State не устанавливается, то есть inline кнопки на команде старт то все ок

Comment: Состояние завершаешь?

Comment: Ты в состоянии находишься, поэтому и не срабатывает, пропиши в функции start - `await state.finish()`